# Remove a contact from Hike which is already deleted from the phone but still showing on Hike

Tags: hike-messenger

How can I remove a contact from Hike which I've deleted from my phone but still showing on Hike?

Comment: Maybe it will synchronise the contacts gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Block the contact. It will remove that from your friend list.

Actually, it shows that contact because it is in your friend list, or you send it a friend request. So, as you block that contact, it cancels the request. Now you unblock the contact again, and it is removed from your friend list.